# May an attribute have no value?

Tags: shortcode

Is it allowed to add an attribute to a shortcode without giving it a value? something like:

```
[shortcode attr1="hasvalue" attr2]
```

The attribute `attr1` has a value, which I can easily catch in a function like: `function shortcode( $atts ) {...` with `$atts['attr1']`.

Can I also catch the other attribute `attr2`? Its value doesn't exist, so `$atts['attr2']` is undefined/empty. But can I maybe simply detect if this attribute has been written or not?

This would be useful for binary settings, such as a true or false indication, where it is a bit redundant to write `true="true"` or something like that.

Comment: Sorta? Check out the discussion here: [https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/10973/shortcode-empty-attribute](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/10973/shortcode-empty-attribute) kingjeffery's answer (which is looping through the $atts array and checking for any attribute with the name) sounds like it might be a fit.

Comment: I have flagged my question as a duplicate of: [Shortcode empty attribute](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/10973/shortcode-empty-attribute)

Comment: @SeanVõKirkpatrick Thank you for the link. This seems to answer my questions. I have marked my question as a duplicate of: [Shortcode empty attribute](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/10973/shortcode-empty-attribute). It seems to be possible to have an attribute with no value, but it is not fool-proof since when you loop after the term `attr2`, it would also fire true if this term was used within another already present attribute.